# Getting Duplicate Values When Joining the Same Table Twice

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

Multiple joins to the same table using different criteria.

I'm trying to get a value from a table but have different criteria. There is a column that has the value I'm trying to retrieve. There are two sets of criteria.

The issue is with the Else line. The logic is, if the conditions in the first join are true, then get the c_wRVUAmt value. If there is no match, then use the conditions from the second join. If there is no match there, then use 0.

I'm getting duplicate records, which I understand. I just don't understand how to write the joins or the query to eliminate duplicate rows.

```sql
select a.[Revenue Id]
      ,a.CPT
      ,a.[Procedure Mod]
      ,dd.MemberId
      ,ee.MemberId
      ,dd.c_HCPCS
      ,ee.c_HCPCS
      ,dd.c_MOD
      ,ee.c_MOD
      ,CASE When a.[GL Company Unit] IN ('6500','6600','6700') and a.[Rev Code] = '0320'
                 then 0 
            When RTRIM(a.[BE Name]) <> 'Hospital'
                 Then 0 
            Else ISNULL(dd.c_wRVUAmt * a.[Total Qty],0)+ISNULL(ee.c_wRVUAmt * a.[Total Qty],0)
      end as WorkRVUAmt 
from GP_CUSTOMS..Revenue_Staging a 
Left Outer Join d_Dim22 dd on a.[CPT] = dd.c_HCPCS
                          and a.[Procedure Mod] = dd.c_MOD
                          and a.[Procedure Mod] in ('26','53')
Left Outer Join d_Dim22 ee on a.[CPT] = ee.c_HCPCS
                          and a.[Procedure Mod] NOT IN ('26','53')
```

I'm looking for one row.

Comment: did you tried `GROUP BY` or `distinct` to avoid duplicates

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: *The issue is with the Else line. ... to eliminate duplicate rows.* -- Are these two separate issues you're facing?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to remove duplicates.
One of these is to select data with a subselect.

Try to put around your select another select WITH DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[Revenue Id]
      ,CPT
      ,[Procedure Mod]
      ,MemberId1
      ,MemberId2
      ,c_HCPCS
      ,c_HCPCS
      ,c_MOD
      ,c_MOD
      ,WorkRVUAmt 
FROM (<YOUR SELECT HERE>)
```

Remember to give an alias to your column names MemberId (e.g. MemberId1, MemberId2)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to eliminate records happen to come out of the left joins provided in your query. You can either write a correlated subquery and pass out a row instead from either of the tables on the right side of the joins or modify the result in the select by distinct which I believe is not your option!